# Magento 2 failed database rollback cannot add foreign key constraints

Tags: magento2, database, magento-2.1.7, backup, foreign-key

I recently updated from magento v. 2.1.7 to 2.1.9 and then tried to update directly after that to 2.2.1. That failed and when i try to do a rollback (backup created before updating from 2.1.7) that also fails so I am stuck between working versions. The error I get when trying to rollback database is this:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint, query was: CREATE TABLE `customer_group` (
  `customer_group_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Customer Group Id',
  `customer_group_code` varchar(32) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Customer Group Code',
  `tax_class_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Tax Class Id',
  PRIMARY KEY (`customer_group_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Customer Group';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the 2.2.0 release the `customer_group_id` field has type `INT(10)`:

```
CREATE TABLE `customer_group` (
 `customer_group_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `customer_group_code` varchar(32) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Customer Group Code',
 `tax_class_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Tax Class Id',
 PRIMARY KEY (`customer_group_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Customer Group'
```

You can update this table manually or check why during update the old type is used.

This is actual for the all tables where the `customer_group_id` field used as a foreign key: its length should be changed to the 10.

Comment: @sandip I'm glad to help You :)

Comment: can this schema change be skipped when very few customer groups are used? problem is when you have 600gb db it will take ages to alter the column and i'm not sure is useful when you are only a b2c seller