# Magento 2 upgrade 2.1.7 to 2.3.2 give error Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed modify column customer_group_id in table of customer_group

Tags: magento2, database, upgrade, customer-group

Can anyone please explain about this type of error Like http://prntscr.com/oow1oz

Also, I refer to this link [Magento 2 failed database rollback cannot add foreign key constraints](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/202472/magento-2-failed-database-rollback-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraints) but not working for me.

so please anyone help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am searching for the various post but not working for me.at last find the solution by me. If Anyone fetches that type of error occur solution is given step by step.

**STEP: 1** Upgrade ***Magento 2.1.7 to 2.2.5***

**STEP: 2** Upgrade  ***Magento 2.2.5 to Latest Version***

May helpfull this answer...
Thank You...
Happy Codding...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution. Run the following query in your mysql database

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

Truncate table **customer_group**

After the upgrade process finished run following query:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response  but still not working give an error like http://prntscr.com/oow1oz

Comment: Can you try this once again by truncating table customer_group

Comment: truncate table query not working because of the foreign key constraint http://prntscr.com/oowfjb

Comment: You have to first unset the foreign key check and after that truncate the table, and again set a foreign key check to 1. Read the above answer again.

Comment: I understand and do as you said but still issue available

Comment: Verify the table foreign key values, Is there any value that exist as foriegn key but not actually available in table

Answer (score 1):

To fix that I followed those steps:

1) Found the referenced foreign key:

```
SELECT
    TABLE_NAME,
    COLUMN_NAME,
    CONSTRAINT_NAME,
    REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,
    REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE
    REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name'
    AND REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'table_name';
```

My result was:

```
+----------------+----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
| TABLE_NAME     | COLUMN_NAME    | CONSTRAINT_NAME                                                | REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME | REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME |
+----------------+----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
| amasty_fpc_log | customer_group | AMASTY_FPC_LOG_CUSTOMER_GROUP_CUSTOMER_GROUP_CUSTOMER_GROUP_ID | customer_group        | customer_group_id      |
+----------------+----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
```

2) Remove foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE `amasty_fpc_log`
    DROP FOREIGN KEY `AMASTY_FPC_LOG_CUSTOMER_GROUP_CUSTOMER_GROUP_CUSTOMER_GROUP_ID`;
```

3) Execute the alter script (or setup:upgrade)

```
ALTER TABLE `customer_group` MODIFY COLUMN `customer_group_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

NOTE: Do a backup before executing any query on database.
NOTE2: You my loose column data after removing foreign key.

I hope it helps.